# Serialize MVC model to JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to do a very simple task: get an MVC model, and send it back to server as JSON. I tried

```
 @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

When debugging the JS, I see that the date objects on the serialized JSON look like: `/date (00064321)/` and when passing the serialized JSON to the server, the dates are null on the server-side. Anyone understand what is going on?

Comment: Post your ajax code and action method so we can see what is going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of JSON encoding the model directly you have to create an anonymous object converting the date-time properties to strings.

Ex.

```
var meeting = new Meeting 
              { 
                  Name = "Project Updates", 
                  StartDateTime = DateTime.Now 
              };
```

Passing directly the model..

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(meeting))
```

produces

```
{"Name":"Project Updates","StartDateTime":"\/Date(1338381576306)\/"}
```

and

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { 
                  Name = meeting.Name, 
                   StartDateTime = meeting.StartDateTime.ToString()
}))
```

produces

```
{"Name":"Project Updates","StartDateTime":"5/30/2012 6:09:36 PM"}
```

as expected.