# How do I serialize and push a ViewModel out to HTML page to use the JSON structure?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I like to push my view model structures out to my View and then use those in javascript.  What is a more elegant way to do this?  These lines of code are kind of ugly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var PartChangeModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PartChange));
       var PartModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Part));
       var BOMItemModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BOMItem));
</script>
```

Comment: here is a similar question, but still doing it like I am:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813636/mvc-serialize-model-to-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestion from A-Dubb, I put this into an extension method.  Which way makes more sense?  Probably 6 and half dozen kind of thing.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ToJson(this Object ObjectToSerialize, string JavascriptVariableName)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("var {0} = {1};", JavascriptVariableName, Json.Encode(ObjectToSerialize)));
        }
```

Then you can call it from Razor like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @Model.PartChange.ToJson("PartChangeModel")
    @Model.Part.ToJson("PartModel")
    @Model.BOMItem.ToJson("BOMItemModel")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mix Razor markup with JavaScript, then an AJAX call would probably be best. Using jQuery you could issue a get request to a controller endpoint that returns your serialized model. The primary caveat of course being that this approach requires an extra round trip to the server on top of the initial page load, but I wouldn't let that stop me.

client side

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('part/get', function(data) {
      // do something with response
    });
}
```

server side

```
public class PartChangeModel { }

public class PartModel { }

public class BOMItemModel { }

public class PartViewModel { }

public class PartController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Get() {
        var partChangeModel = new PartChangeModel { /* init properties via repo, etc. */ }
        var partModel = new PartModel { /* init properties via repo, etc. */ }
        var bomItemModel = new BOMItemModel { /* init properties via repo, etc. */ }

        var viewModel = new PartViewModel {
            PartChangeModel = partChangeModel,
            PartModel = partModel,
            BOMItemModel = bomItemModel
        }

        return Json(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, i thought about that but I strive so much to keep my HTTP calls down, I was still hoping to push it server side.  I do enough HTTP calls pulling all of my json data.  :)

Comment: One other approach I tend to take is to implement a .ToJson() extension method on object and put it atop something like Newtonsoft.Json. So in your view, you could do something like var PartChangeModel = @Model.PartChange.ToJson();
    var PartModel =@Model.Part.ToJson();
    var BOMItemModel = @Model.BOMItem.ToJson();

Comment: Wasn't aware that tick marks apparently get escaped/html encoded so I guess you would need to do that unless you used the @: syntax which renders plain text. http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode

Comment: I created a HTML helper for this.  I thought about an extension method, but what type of object would I be extending, object?  I wouldn't want that method to appear on everything.

Comment: That's why you'd namespace it. It'd only show up once you referenced that namespace. Just like you have to add using System.Linq before you can call Select, Where, OrderBy, etc.

Comment: Okay A-Dubb, I added an extension method version below.  They both work the same.  Which do you like?  You can post an answer and I will accept yours since it was your suggestion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23173/discussion-between-a-dubb-and-shane)

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with some HTML Helpers for this.  This seems to work.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString SerializeJsonForClient(this HtmlHelper helper, string JavascriptVariableName, object ObjectToSerialize)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("var {0} = {1};", JavascriptVariableName, Json.Encode(ObjectToSerialize)));
        }
```

Then you can call it from Razor like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @Html.SerializeJsonForClient("PartChangeModel", Model.PartChange)
    @Html.SerializeJsonForClient("PartModel", Model.Part)
    @Html.SerializeJsonForClient("BOMItemModel", Model.BOMItem)
</script>
```